# How to add this in a list?

Tags: java, list, arraylist, collections

```
final  List<S> s = new ArrayList<S>();
```

I have created 3 objects and added them in a list

```
    A a = new("l", "m"); // creating object a 
    B b = new ("n", "o"); // createing b obj
    C c = new("p", "q"); // creating c obj
```

Now I add `a`, `b`, `c` in a list

```
    s.add(a); // adding to the list s

    s.add(b); // adding to the list s

    s.add(c); // adding to the list s
```

Now I have to add Type for A, B, and C. Like

```
  a.setType("Z"); // a, b and c have same Type   
  b.setType("z"); // a, b, c have same type
  c.setType("z"); // a,,b , c have same type
```

So instead of doing this 3 times, can I do this only once

Now `a` , `b`, and `c` have same type which I have to pass. How to do this? 
Can someone suggest something to me please?

Comment: can you please sort the question properly, please? Is quite unreadable...

Comment: `A a = new("l", "m"); // creating object a` creating nothing this doesn't compile, you probably meant `A a = new A("l", "m");`

Comment: Is it intentional that your type for `a` is uppercase, while for the others that is lowercase?

Comment: What is `A`, `B` and `C`? Do they extend `S`? You might need to use `List<? extends S> list = new ArrayList<>();`.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a loop with a for cicle:

```
    for ( int i = 0; i < s.getSize(); ++i )
          s.get(i).setType("Z");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code after adding a, b, c to the list:

```
for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++) {
    s.get(i).setType("Z");
}
```

get(i) gets you the i-th element in the List s and s.size() gives you the number of elements in the same list.
So setting up the loop in the above manner will run the loop for the number of elements in the list and set the type of each to "Z".